# How to view the B-tree index structure generated by InnoDB of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

Is there a way to view the B-tree index structure generated by InnoDB when we specify B-tree index for an attribute of a table?

Comment: Why?  What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to compare the tree structure with the result yielded when I apply `EXPLAIN` to the `SELECT` query on this attribute.

Comment: Sounds like you want to precisely count the number of blocks or rows to be accessed?  `EXPLAIN` gives crude, sometimes far-off, values.

Comment: That is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no official tools to view the internals of InnoDB B-tree index structures.

There's an experimental set of tools to examine the internals of InnoDB pages, but it won't display the B-tree in a human-readable way. https://github.com/jeremycole/innodb_ruby

But I believe you're asking for a thing that will not have useful information anyway.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-physical-structure.html says:

> With the exception of spatial indexes, InnoDB indexes are B-tree data structures.

Specifying `USING BTREE` for the index type is redundant when using InnoDB. Whether you specify it or not, it will be a B-tree. There is no difference when you specify that index option.

Other storage engines (MEMORY, NDB) support `HASH` as an alternative index type.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-storage-engine-index-types